# HTML5 Canvas: How to keep shape moving infinitely at constant rate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Basically, I have my triangle moving when I press one of the arrow keys in a certain direction but then stops right after I let go of the key. I want to accelerate and then let go of the key and let the triangle accelerate at that same speed for an infinite amount of time. Here is my relevant code:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var rotationDegrees = 0;

var movementRate = 5;
var rotationRate = 5;

function draw(){

    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    drawTriangle(context, x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight, rotationDegrees);


    if (rotationDegrees > 360){
        rotationDegrees = 0;
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log('this is where I describe the log: keydown event.which', event.which);


    switch(event.which){
        case 37:
        console.log('left');
        rotationDegrees = rotationDegrees - rotationRate;
        break;
        case 38:
        console.log('up');
        x = x + movementRate * Math.cos(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
        y = y + movementRate * Math.sin(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
        break;
        case 39:
        console.log('right');
        rotationDegrees = rotationDegrees + rotationRate;
        break;
        case 40:
        console.log('down');
        x = x - movementRate * Math.cos(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
        y = y - movementRate * Math.sin(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
        break;
        default:
    }
});



function drawTriangle(context, x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight, rotationDegrees){
    context.save();

    var centerX = x + rectWidth/2;
    var centerY = y + rectHeight/2;

    context.translate(centerX, centerY); 

    var radians = rotationDegrees * (Math.PI/180);
    context.rotate(radians);



    context.strokeStyle = 'red';

    context.beginPath();


    var triangleOriginX = rectWidth/2;
    var triangleOriginY = rectHeight/2;

    context.moveTo(-triangleOriginX , -triangleOriginY);
    context.lineTo(-triangleOriginX  + rectWidth, -triangleOriginY + rectHeight/2);
    context.lineTo(-triangleOriginX, -triangleOriginY + rectHeight);

    context.closePath();

    context.stroke();

    context.restore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you key event handler code replace the code for setting `x` and `y` with code setting delta values. Then in you main loop update `x` and `y` using those deltas. Otherwise the position will only update when a (correct) key is pressed.

```
// ...
case 38:
  dx = movementRate * Math.cos(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
  dy = movementRate * Math.sin(rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180);
  // ... etc.
```

Then in the loop:

```
function draw(){
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    // ...rest of code
```

You will of course have to implement some checks and balances here as well as declaring `dx` and `dy`.